# How to adjust image on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How should I adjust Slider images on different type of screens? I am using Bootstrap.

1. For the Slider if I am using an image of dimensions: 1920px *1228px; it is using complete height of a Laptop screen, but when viewed on a mobile screen- it covers approx. 30% of a mobile screen.(as mobile width is comparatively less than height).
2. On the other hand if I am trying to use an image of size 1600*400px; on a laptop screen it is taking approx 30% of height & that is looking good as per my site, but with this, on I mobile screen its looking very small and bad.

Should I add some CSS or something else?

Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

      <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="images/Cimg5.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/Cimg2.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="images/Cimg3.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

     <div class="item">
        <img src="images/Cimg4.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div> 

    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: have you tried adding the img-responsive class to your img elements?

Comment: I tried it just now. But not getting any useful result. My problem seems to be due to change in aspect ratio between two types of screens.. In Laptop we have width larger than height, whereas in mobiles Height is more...

Comment: It is possible to review your total code snippet or jsfiddle? Seems this is happening for your image ratio.

Comment: Do you mean you want to take a look at complete HTML file? I think you are guessing correct, its problem with image ratio. Please advise what image ratio/dimensions should be used for slider image. On Laptop & Desktop screens I want an image covering full width and 40-50% height.

Answer (score 0):

use `viewport` in head then check.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```